# Placing divs next to another dynamic size div

Tags: css, image, html

I need to place the three divs with ids "divThumbnail", "bannerImageProgress" and "divRemoveBanner" inside the div with the id "wrapper" as displayed in the image. What is loaded into "divThumbnail" div is an image, which could be of changing size. I need the "bannerImageProgress" to be right to the left of the "divThumbnail" and the "divRemoveBanner" to be right below it. Since the size of divThumbnail can dynamically change defining absolute positions(as shown in the code) does not produce the desired behavior.

This is how I need it: [div with progress bar right next to the image and the div with remove word right below the image]

[image]

For square shaped images, the "bannerImageProgress" div is not shown next to the image:

[image]

my HTML code so far:

```
    <div id="wrapper" class="image-area-container">
       <div id="divThumbnail" class="image_outer_div" style="width: 200px; height: 60px; ">
           @if ( Model.HasBanner ) {
           <img id = "bannerThumbnail" src = "@Model.BannerLink" />
           }
       </div>
       <div id = "bannerImageProgress" class = "progress progress-success" style="display: inline-block; float: left; left: 566px;">
           <div id = "bannerImage" class = "bar" style = "float: left; width: 0%;" data-percentage="0">
           </div>
       </div>

       <div id="divRemoveBanner" style="display:none;">
        <a id="removeBanner">Remove</a>
       </div>
    </div>

CSS:

<!-- language: lang-css -->

    .image-area-container {
        float: left;
        width: 65px;
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .image_outer_div { 
        height: 60px; 
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 200px; 
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
    }

    .image_area .progress {
        left: 346px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 4px;
        width: 200px;
     }
```

Thanks in advance! :)

After applying the changes suggested by Ali:

It did not go well. Now the "divThumbnail" div and the "bannerImageProgress" divs overlaps :( Like this:-

[image]

Code after changes:-

```
<div class="image-area-container" style="position:relative; width: 400px;">

                        <div id="divThumbnail" class="image_outer_div" style="width: 200px; height: 60px; float: left; ">
                            @if (Model.HasBanner)
                            {
                                <img id="bannerThumbnail" src="@Model.BannerLink" />
                            }

                        </div>

                        <div id="bannerImageProgress" class="progress progress-success" style="display: inline-block; clear:both; position:absolute; left:0; right:0;">
                            <div id="bannerImage" class="bar" style="float: left; width: 0%;" data-percentage="0">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    <div id="divRemoveBanner" style="display:none; clear:both; float: left;">
                        <a id="removeBanner">Remove</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
```

Comment: Add rendered html code with dummy image link\

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you float the progress bar right and the other two left?
or
Give the image another div wrapper with a fixed width?